# Sharepoint's installation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm a newbie in Sharepoint 2010 and need some help.

I have downloaded two programs från Microsoft Academy for students
*SharePoint Designer 2010 (x86 - English)
*SharePoint Server 2010 (x64) - DVD (English)

Which of these programs do I need I started installing?

I also heard that you need to have a server in order to use Sharepoint. In my case I only have a Dell laptop (XPS M1710) with XP pro.

can I still use Sharepoint with full utilization without using a server?

// Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 Server is 64-bit only, and can only be installed on a Windows Server unless you do a [SKU Hack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx). Even then, I doubt it will want to install on Windows XP. Vista or Windows 7 is going to be required.

The designer is used purely as a simple content editor for an existing SharePoint installation.

Comment: I understand. I have two more questions.                                

*Unfortunately, I don't understand clearly the difference between Sharepoint designer and Sharepoint Server?                            

*Does Sharepoint promote loose decoupling as ASP.net MVC 2 does?

Comment: SP Server IS sharepoint itself. SP designer is, as jones says, purely a client program for editing content on the SharePoint server - eg page layouts, text, libraries, themes etc. You don't strictly need it if youre not doing anything advanced. As for loose coupling - I have no idea what the code is like behind SP, I don't really care, and neither should you - SP is designed to allow you to not write a single line of code for 99% of SP projects. It does provide an API however: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx. PS sharepoint definately wont run on your XP laptop